# Add Duplicate Double quotes to a string

Tags: unix

I have the following list of words:

```
1,"London","This is "London" which has, many streets","IST1"
```

I need to have it double quoted like this, its a search pattern for 2nd occurance and add double quote as mentioned, csv input file with no fixed position for ":

```
1,"London","This is ""London"" which has, many streets","IST1"
```

I have tried `sed 's/.*/\"&\"/g'` and not working

Above solution needs extra double quote .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the above fixed format, this would work if no extra quotes are present.

```
$ sed 's/"*"/\"\"/4' test.txt | sed 's/"*"/\"\"/5'
```

Output:

```
$ cat test.txt 
  1,"London","This is "London" which has, many streets","IST1"
  2,"India","This is "India" which has, many cultures","IST10"

$ sed 's/"*"/\"\"/4' test.txt | sed 's/"*"/\"\"/5' 
  1,"London","This is ""London"" which has, many streets","IST1"
  2,"India","This is ""India"" which has, many cultures","IST10"
```

Now, if there is no constraint on which technology you use, I would suggest you use Pandas as this is definitely a CSV file and editing it would become fairly easy in Pandas, [to read more about Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29)

Comment: I;ve just provided London as an example, it needs to check for any value within the string (as mentioned) and then add double quotes with in that particular column

Comment: Thanks Mukund, it's not the fixed format, it needs to search for double quotes with in the column and then add one more double quotes, the above answer is for fixed, so not suffice for the requirement